# Power BI power KPI Charts

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a target and current amount of data in a power KPI chart. I have tried a lot but the lines are not shown properly in the chart. I have attached a screenshot of my chart.

I want to show the target and the current status separately via lines per month.

[image]

Comment: Have you created a KPI with Value and Goal or you just have 2 separate measures for current vs targeted?

Comment: @Mboolean theres no KPI measures.But there are two separate values for Target and current value.

Answer (score 0):

try using Gauge Visual it will give you both in this i am unable to understand your data can to please share what are the fields you are using and how

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-radial-gauge-charts
above will show you how to use Gauge

Answer (score 0):

Drag the line-chart from the visualizations pane and then add Date to axis then drop current and target values under the value field.

[image]

If not working then post sample data to work with.